Rasa NLU returning empty list
I am facing an issue with my Rasa NLU model where it returns an empty list when the user's question or prompt is related to confirm_order or cancel_order intents. Although the model is trained with enough examples for these purposes, it seems to struggle to recognize them in some situations.
Here are some details about my setup:

I'm using Rasa version 3.1.
I have defined intents like confirm_order and cancel_order in my NLU training data, with examples covering various confirmation and cancellation requests.
Other intents in my model like get_food_category and get_food_items work as expected.

when a user asks to confirm or cancel an order, the model fails to recognize these intents and returns an empty list.
Additionally, when I check the intent of the user message with http://localhost:5005/model/parse, it correctly identifies the intent. However, Rasa gives an empty list for these purposes.
Here is my nlu.yml file
version: "3.1"

nlu:
- intent: get_food_category
  examples: |
    - What are some well-known cuisines? 
    - Could you recommend some famous culinary traditions? 
    - Tell me about diverse types of cuisines. 
    - Can you list some globally recognized food cultures? 
    - Which cuisines have gained popularity worldwide? 
    - I'm curious about different culinary heritages. 
    - What are some widely celebrated food traditions? 
    - Can you introduce me to various culinary styles? 
    - I want to explore different gastronomic experiences. 
    - Which food cultures have left a significant mark on global cuisine? 
    - Tell me about some iconic cuisines from around the world. 
    - What are some traditional culinary practices from different regions? 
    - Can you highlight some culinary delights from diverse backgrounds? 
    - I'm interested in learning about various culinary influences. 
    - Which cuisines are celebrated for their unique flavors? 
    - What are some notable culinary traditions celebrated internationally? 
    - Tell me about some lesser-known culinary gems. 
    - Can you recommend some underrated food cultures? 
    - I want to discover hidden culinary treasures. 
    - Which cuisines offer distinct taste experiences?

- intent: get_food_items
  examples: |
    - List dishes from [Indian](category) cuisine.
    - Give me some [Japanese](category) food options.
    - What are common dishes in [American](category) cuisine?
    - Tell me about traditional [Thai](category) dishes.
    - Any popular [French](category) recipes?
    - What are some signature dishes from [Italian](category) cuisine?
    - Can you suggest some appetizers from [Mediterranean](category) cuisine?
    - I'm craving some [Mexican](category) street food. Any recommendations?
    - What are some classic dishes from [Chinese](category) cuisine?
    - Tell me about some unique [Korean](category) dishes.
    - Give me some examples of [Greek](category) desserts.
    - What are some traditional breakfast foods from [British](category) cuisine?
    - Can you list some vegan options from [Vietnamese](category) cuisine?
    - What are some popular dishes from [Spanish](category) cuisine?
    - Tell me about some comfort foods from [American](category) cuisine.
    - What are some famous [north Indian](category) dishes?
    - What are some healthy options from [Mediterranean](category) cuisine?
    - Give me some examples of [Indian](category) street food.
    - What are some famous dishes from [Japanese](category) cuisine?
    - Can you recommend some seafood dishes from [Italian](category) cuisine?
    - What are some must-try dishes from [Thai](category) cuisine?

- intent: order_food
  examples: |
    - I'd like to try [paneer butter masala](food) tonight.
    - Can you recommend some [vegetarian thali](food) options?
    - I'm craving [fish curry](food) for dinner.
    - Please bring me some [aloo tikki](food) as an appetizer.
    - I want to have [masala dosa](food) for breakfast.
    - Can I get some [chicken korma](food), please?
    - I'd like to order [pav bhaji](food) for lunch.
    - What are some popular [street food](food) options?
    - Can you serve me some [rajma chawal](food) for dinner?
    - I'm in the mood for [mutton biryani](food) tonight.
    - Please bring me some [puri bhaji](food) for breakfast.
    - I want to try [jalebi](food) for dessert.
    - Can you recommend some [chaat](food) options?
    - I'd like to have [masoor dal](food) for lunch.
    - Could you bring me some [kulcha](food) as a side dish?
    - I'm craving [kaju katli](food) for dessert.
    - Please serve me some [paneer tikka masala](food).
    - Can you recommend some [traditional sweets](food)?
    - I'd like to try [pulao](food) for dinner.

- intent: inform_quantity
  examples: |
    - I'll take [three](quantity) servings, please
    - Could you put down [4](quantity) plates for me?
    - Add [six](quantity) portions to my order
    - I'd like [seven](quantity) orders of that, please
    - Can you make it [eight](quantity) servings?
    - I want [9](quantity) plates
    - Please add [ten](quantity) portions to my order
    - Put down [11](quantity) servings, thank you
    - I'll go with [twelve](quantity) plates this time
    - Make it [thirteen](quantity) orders, please
    - I'd like [14](quantity) servings of that dish
    - Add [fifteen](quantity) portions to my cart, please
    - Can you add [sixteen](quantity) plates to my order?
    - I'll take [seventeen](quantity) orders of that, thank you
    - Please make it [eighteen](quantity) servings
    - Add [nineteen](quantity) portions to my order, please
    - Could you put down [20](quantity) plates for me?
    - I want [twenty-one](quantity) servings, please
    - Can you add [twenty-two](quantity) portions to my order?
    - I'll take [twenty-three](quantity) orders of that dish

- intent: confirm_order
  examples: |
    - Yes, my order is correct.
    - That's exactly what I want. Please proceed with the order.
    - Yes, I confirm the order.
    - Everything looks good. You can proceed with the order.
    - I confirm the items and quantities mentioned in the order.
    - Yes, I'd like to confirm my order.
    - Please go ahead and place the order.
    - Yes, that's what I want. Please confirm the order.
    - I'm happy with the order. You can proceed.
    - Confirm the order with the items mentioned.
    - Yes, I'm ready to confirm my order.
    - Please confirm the order with the specified items.
    - That's correct. Please confirm the order.
    - I confirm the order as mentioned.
    - Yes, I confirm. Please proceed with the order.
    - Confirming the order with the items specified.
    - Yes, that's it. Please confirm the order.
    - Everything looks good to me. Confirm the order, please.
    - Yes, please confirm the order with the listed items.
    - Confirming the order. Everything seems correct

- intent: cancel_order
  examples: |
    - No, I want to cancel the order.
    - Please cancel my order.
    - I changed my mind. Cancel the order, please.
    - No, I don't want to proceed with the order. Cancel it.
    - I'd like to cancel my order.
    - Can you cancel the order for me?
    - I decided not to go ahead with the order. Cancel it, please.
    - No, cancel the order.
    - I want to cancel my order and try something else.
    - Please cancel the order. I no longer want it.
    - Cancel the order. I've changed my mind.
    - I'd like to cancel the order I placed earlier.
    - No, I don't want to confirm the order. Cancel it.
    - I've decided to cancel the order. Please proceed accordingly.
    - Cancel the order. I'm no longer interested.
    - Please cancel my order as soon as possible.
    - I don't want the order anymore. Cancel it.
    - Cancel my order. I won't be needing it anymore.
    - I'd like to cancel the order I placed earlier today.
    - I've changed my mind. Can you cancel the order, please?

Here is my stories.yml file
version: "3.1"

stories:

- story: happy path
  steps:
  - intent: get_food_category
  - action: action_get_food_category
  - intent: get_food_items
  - slot_was_set:
    - category: Indian
  - action: action_get_food_items
  - intent: order_food
  - slot_was_set:
    - food: Chicken Curry
  - action: action_order_food
  - intent: inform_quantity
  - slot_was_set:
    - quantity: 2
  - action: action_inform_quantity
  - intent: confirm_order
  - action: action_confirm_order


- story: sad path 1
  steps:
  - intent: get_food_category
  - action: action_get_food_category
  - intent: get_food_items
  - slot_was_set:
    - category: Indian
  - action: action_get_food_items
  - intent: order_food
  - slot_was_set:
    - food: Chicken Curry
  - action: action_order_food
  - intent: inform_quantity
  - slot_was_set:
    - quantity: 2
  - action: action_inform_quantity
  - intent: cancel_order
  - action: action_cancel_order

Here is my domain.yml file
version: "3.1"

intents:
  - get_food_category
  - get_food_items
  - order_food
  - inform_quantity
  - confirm_order
  - cancel_order

actions:
  - action_get_food_category
  - action_get_food_items
  - action_order_food
  - action_inform_quantity
  - action_confirm_order
  - action_cancel_order

entities:
  - category
  - food
  - quantity

slots:
  category:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: category
  food:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: food
  quantity:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: quantity

session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true

Note: I didn't set any rules in the rules.yml file
Can someone help me understand why Rasa fails to recognize the confirm_order and cancel_order intents and how I can resolve this issue? Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I am not sure about the root cause of this error. Deleting the current model and retraining seems to solve the problem once, but it happens again and again. I don't know what is the root cause of this problem.

I think you should test your bot in rasa interactive mode.

@Hasnain, I am trying in interactive mode but what could be the error related to this issue

I've tried on my local machine, and action_default_fallback keeps occurring. I believe you should divide your stories into multiple sub-stories. Here's therasa logs. Additionally, I think you should share your config.yml as well. Have tried it with forms approach?

@Hasnain, Even though I tried with the form, I got the problem, I don't know what is going wrong.
